# How to ignore Jasmine promises when "no-floating-promises" in tslint is true

Tags: typescript, protractor, tslint, jasmine2.0

Is there a way to have "no-floating-promises" turned on but let it ignore Jasmine promises like "toEqual", "toBe", etc.? I want to use it, but it complains about my expect statements all over the place.

```js
expect(1).toEqual(1)  // Would complain about this
```

For example: [image]

Comment: update the question with you implementation and the complete error log

Answer (score 3):

I use `void` keyword for the jasmine expect. Although there is some discussion about how appropriate that is: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4653

```js
void expect(1).toEqual(1)  // Would not complain about this
```

Comment: Works but don't like the solution since now every expect must be preceded by void